# Invoke keyboard shortcuts with one key

Tags: applescript, case, systemevent

I have created three keyboard shortcuts to right-click menu items on my Mac that work in any application:

When text is selected:

Capitalize is <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

Make Lower Case is <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>

Make Upper Case is <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>

Makes sense but now that is laid out I'd like to create an Applescript to invoke these shortcuts with just the <kbd>CAPS</kbd> key.

What I'd like is:

When text is selected:

Double-click <kbd>CAPS</kbd> invokes <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

If text is UC single click <kbd>CAPS</kbd> invokes <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>

If text is LC single click <kbd>CAPS</kbd> invokes <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>

Otherwise <kbd>CAPS</kbd> acts as normal.

Is there a way to do this? Keyboard Settings wouldn't allow me to use <kbd>CAPS</kbd> as a hotkey/shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to be hard if not impossible to do. I have written Applescripts in the past to detect caps lock down or up.([one such as this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080202094656148)) But they are clunky to setup. And require other components to be running and then even if i used or wrote an Application in Objective-C it means a third party app has to be running.

The simplest solution is to use your Function keys. You can use three of them  one for each

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) to change caps lock to another key (like F19), and then add something like this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook:

`<autogen>__DoublePressModifier__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>`

Or for holding the key:

`<autogen>__HoldingKeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::VK_NONE, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, Option::NOREPEAT</autogen>`

You can use Automator to create a service for converting to lowercase / uppercase. Check output replaces selected text and add a run shell script action like this:

```
export LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
input=$(cat)
grep -q [[:upper:]] <<< "$input" && \
printf %s "$input" | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]] || \
printf %s "$input" | tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]]
```

You can give it a shortcut (like ⌘F19) in System Preferences.

Automator uses the C locale by default, so without LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 character classes would only include ASCII characters.